# How to type this table

Tags: tables

I want to type this table in LaTeX:

- Cell A should have an automatic width, according to its content;
- Cell B has a fixed width (e.g. 10 cm), and the text inside will wrap;
- Cell C has a width of the sum of A and B, and of course allow text to wrap.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabularx` is most suitable for such cases. To fulfill the requirements you provided, cell A should be specified `l` and cell `B` should fill the remaining space (but not a fixed width as you said in the question) by specifying `X` column type for it. Finally, cell C is a little more tricky. It should occupy a length equal to the sum of `cell A + cell B`, but still you have to subtract two `\tabcolsep`s plus two `\arrayrulewidth`s. This is achieved by using `p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}` for cell C.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
cell A & Cell B has a fixed width (e.g. 10 cm), and the text inside will wrap; \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{Cell C has a width of the sum of A and B, and of course allow text to wrap.} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! But the answer is still not perfect: the width of text in cell C is just the same as cell B, but not A+B.

Comment: Yes, please see my edit for the exact cell size for cell C.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, your table width is variable, depending only on what is contained in Cell A. To that end, you can measure the width of Cell A using [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module; specifically, `\zsaveposx{<mark>}` to save the `x`-coordinate (in `s`caled `p`oints or `sp`s) on the page as `<mark>`. This can then be used in `dim`ension `expr`essions to calculate the width of the second row:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{10cm} | }
  \hline
  \zsaveposx{CellAl-1}Cell \texttt{A}\zsaveposx{CellAr-1} & 
    Cell \texttt{B} has a fixed width (\textit{e.g.}, \texttt{10cm}), and the text inside will wrap to the following line; \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{| p{\dimexpr10cm+\zposx{CellAr-1}sp-\zposx{CellAl-1}sp+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth} |}{%
    Cell \texttt{C} has a width of the sum of \texttt{A} and \texttt{B}, and of course allow text to wrap to subsequent
    lines as needed, regardless of what is presented in \texttt{A}.%
  } \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{10cm} | }
  \hline
  \zsaveposx{CellAl-2}Cell \texttt{A} plus stuff\zsaveposx{CellAr-2} & 
    Cell \texttt{B} has a fixed width (\textit{e.g.}, \texttt{10cm}), and the text inside will wrap to the following line; \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{| p{\dimexpr10cm+\zposx{CellAr-2}sp-\zposx{CellAl-2}sp+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth} |}{%
    Cell \texttt{C} has a width of the sum of \texttt{A} and \texttt{B}, and of course allow text to wrap to subsequent
    lines as needed, regardless of what is presented in \texttt{A}.%
  } \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Cell A is set inside a `l`eft-aligned column, which expands naturally to fit the content. Cell B is fixed at 10cm. The width of Cell C accommodates for the width of Cell A (`\zposx{<right>}sp-\zposx{<left>}`), 2 regular `\tabcolsep`s inserted around the vertical rule between Cell A and B, one rule width, and 10cm.

Since this uses the a `\label`-`\ref`-like system, you need to compile at least twice if anything within Cell A changes.